# Docker + django + gunicorn connect to Nginx of the host system

Tags: django, docker, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

On ubuntu server 18.04
I run a docker container with Django 3.1 and Gunicorn
which connects to a locally installed Postgres.

I already have an another Django project with Nginx and Gunicorn on the same server without docker.

The questions are: **how to set up socket files for Gunicorn in a container and connect this container to the existing external Nginx so I can access the containerized django app from outside?**

*docker-compose.prod.yml*

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
   build:
     context: .
   ports:
     - "8001:8001"
   volumes:
     - ./app:/app
   env_file:
     - .env.prod
   command: >
     sh -c "gunicorn app.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8001"
```

I run the container like this:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up
```

.env.prod

```
...
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS='111.111.111.111 .mysitename.com localhost 172.18.0.1 127.0.0.1 [::1]'
...
```

when running container executing of this command:

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/admin/login/?next=/admin/'
```

gives me the html code of the admin page and it's ok.

The existing Nginx is set up as in these digital ocean tutorials:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04

I also secured it with Let's encrypt using this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is simpler than I thought.

in Nginx conf file

/etc/nginx/sites-available/ edit like that

```
server {
    server_name 111.111.111.111 domainname.com www.domainname.com *.domainname.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/user/<my-previous-project-installed-locally>/project-app;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
   }

   # Added for the NEW application
###############################################
    location  /MY-NEW-PATH/ {
        rewrite ^/MY-NEW-PATH(.*) $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }
###############################################

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainname.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = www.domainname.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
```